# jQuery Autocomplete - Show List on Double Click

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I'm creating an autocomplete on a web page using jQuery's AutoComplete plugin.

Does anyone know how to make the list show, if for example, someone has entered 3 characters, then clicked out of the input box, but then goes back to it?

```
$("#details_business_trade").autocomplete({
    source: resultsSplit,
    autoFill: true,
    mustMatch: true,
    close: function() { $("#createProspect").validate().element("#details_business_trade"); },
    mustMatch: true
});
```

This is my code so far...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can trigger a search using the current value when it's re-focused by using the [`search` method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#method-search), like this:

```
$("#details_business_trade").autocomplete({
    source: resultsSplit,
    autoFill: true,
    mustMatch: true,
    close: function() { $("#createProspect").validate().element("#details_business_trade"); },
    mustMatch: true
}).focus(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete("search");
});
```

It's not your example, [but here's a jQuery UI Demo updated with the same concept](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/v3bXn/), search for "act" for example.

Comment: Basically, if the user has entered 'Art' then clicked out of the input box, but go back to it, it shows immediately the relevant matches...

Comment: @Sjwdavies - Ah, I see what you're after, one moment :)

Comment: @Sjwdavies - Updated with what I think you're after, give it a shot :)

Comment: @Nick Craver: That's awesome, you've no idea how long i've been trying to figure this out! Thanks Buddy!

Comment: @ Nick Craver: Off original thread, but do you know how I can make the list a scrollable one?

Comment: @Sjwdavies - Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/v3bXn/1/ should test it in IE to make sure though.

Comment: @Nick Craver: That's very cool but I was thinking more along the lines of 'scroll: true' or something ?

Comment: @Sjwdavies - There's no built-in support for it yet, it has been requested by the community quite a bit though, so we should see it in a future jQuery UI release.

Comment: @Nick Craver: Nick, I've checked this in IE this morning, and unfortunately your fix doesn't work. It works fine in FF, but when I click on a suggestion from the drop down list - IE still shows the list item. So i've got the answer in my text box, but also a single element in the drop down list - the same as the one in my text box... Is there a way to hide it if the list item is the same as the contents of the text box?

Comment: According to the documentation (http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search) if you set the options object with `minLength: 0` and then change the above call from `.focus(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete("search");
});` to `.focus(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete("search","");
});` then it will work directly on focus without having to type anything first. The reason is because by default `minLength` is set to 1. Which means,  it requires you to type something before a search is done. Worked for me. Yay! Thanks for this question OP. :)